# Python Need Help Simplifying A For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way I can simplify the long for loop I have in my example with a few nested for loops? I'm writing to a CSV in the long loop.

Here's the long loop with:

```py
int_1 = 1
int_2 = 2
interface = 41
for i in range(1, 5):
    # t2-a-1
    writer.writerow(
        [
            f"t2-a-1 Twe1/0/{int_1}",
            f"t1-a-{i} Twe1/0/{interface}",
        ]
    )
    writer.writerow(
        [
            f"t2-a-1 Twe1/0/{int_2}",
            f"t1-a-{i} Twe1/0/{interface + 1}",
        ]
    )
    # t2-a-2
    writer.writerow(
        [
            f"t2-a-2 Twe1/0/{int_1}",
            f"t1-a-{i} Twe1/0/{interface + 2}",
        ]
    )
    writer.writerow(
        [
            f"t2-a-2 Twe1/0/{int_2}",
            f"t1-a-{i} Twe1/0/{interface + 3}",
        ]
    )
    # t2-a-3
    writer.writerow(
        [
            f"t2-a-3 Twe1/0/{int_1}",
            f"t1-a-{i} Twe1/0/{interface + 4}",
        ]
    )
    writer.writerow(
        [
            f"t2-a-3 Twe1/0/{int_2}",
            f"t1-a-{i} Twe1/0/{interface + 5}",
        ]
    )
    # t2-a-4
    writer.writerow(
        [
            f"t2-a-4 Twe1/0/{int_1}",
            f"t1-a-{i} Twe1/0/{interface + 6}",
        ]
    )
    writer.writerow(
        [
            f"t2-a-4 Twe1/0/{int_2}",
            f"t1-a-{i} Twe1/0/{interface + 7}",
        ]
    )
    int_1 += 2
    int_2 += 2
```

The output that I need should look like this:

```
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/48
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/48
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/48
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/48
```

This is what I've tried, but it needs some tweaking:

```py
int_1 = 1
int_2 = 2
interface = 41
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(8):
        if j % 2 == 0:
            thisint = int_1
        else:
            thisint = int_2
        print(f"t2-a-1 Twe1/0/{thisint},t1-a-{i} Twe1/0/{interface + j}")
    int_1 += 2
    int_2 += 2
```

Which produces:

```
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/48
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/48
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/48
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/48
```

How can I tweak the simplified code to do what I want?

Comment: Note that your intended output doesn't match the original code. `interface` should increase incrementally, but its output follows the `int_1` and `int_2` pattern, and vice versa. The actual output from your adjusted code matches the what the original code would produce. So it's unclear which output you really want, since the initial example is incorrect.

Comment: @Ryan Are you sure that the output that you show in your question is exactly the output that you need? In fact the output of your *long for loop* is not the output that you show in the question.

Comment: @frankfalse I updated the long loop's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your output, you could maybe use:

```
interface = 41
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(8):
        print(f't2-a-{i+1} Twe1/0/{j+1},t1-a-{j//2+1} Twe1/0/{interface+2*i+j%2}')
```

*NB. using `print` for quick reproducibility here, replace with `writer.writerow` in your context.*

Output:

```
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/41
t2-a-1 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/42
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/43
t2-a-2 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/44
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/45
t2-a-3 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/46
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/1,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/2,t1-a-1 Twe1/0/48
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/3,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/4,t1-a-2 Twe1/0/48
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/5,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/6,t1-a-3 Twe1/0/48
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/7,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/47
t2-a-4 Twe1/0/8,t1-a-4 Twe1/0/48
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intended output is correct, then you can simply use

```
thisint = 41
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(8):
        print("t2-a-{i} Twe1/0/{j+1},t1-a-{j//2+1} Twe1/0/{thisint + j % 2}")
    thisint += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses 2 for loop and divides the elements for the output, in 3 parts:

- `first_element`: it depends from the value of `i` and `j`
- `int_` value: it depends only from `j`
- `interface_` (that depends from the value of `interface` and `j`)

```
interface = 41
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(0, 8):

        # set the first_element
        first_element = f"t2-a-{i} Twe1/0/{j+1}"

        # set int_ value
        int_ = j//2 + 1

        # set interface value
        interface_ = interface + j%2

        print([first_element, f"t1-a-{int_} Twe1/0/{interface_}", ])
        #writer.writerow([first_element, f"t1-a-{int_} Twe1/0/{interface_}", ])

    interface += 2
```

The output of `print()` is the following:

```
['t2-a-1 Twe1/0/1', 't1-a-1 Twe1/0/41']
['t2-a-1 Twe1/0/2', 't1-a-1 Twe1/0/42']
['t2-a-1 Twe1/0/3', 't1-a-2 Twe1/0/41']
['t2-a-1 Twe1/0/4', 't1-a-2 Twe1/0/42']
['t2-a-1 Twe1/0/5', 't1-a-3 Twe1/0/41']
['t2-a-1 Twe1/0/6', 't1-a-3 Twe1/0/42']
['t2-a-1 Twe1/0/7', 't1-a-4 Twe1/0/41']
['t2-a-1 Twe1/0/8', 't1-a-4 Twe1/0/42']
['t2-a-2 Twe1/0/1', 't1-a-1 Twe1/0/43']
['t2-a-2 Twe1/0/2', 't1-a-1 Twe1/0/44']
['t2-a-2 Twe1/0/3', 't1-a-2 Twe1/0/43']
['t2-a-2 Twe1/0/4', 't1-a-2 Twe1/0/44']
['t2-a-2 Twe1/0/5', 't1-a-3 Twe1/0/43']
['t2-a-2 Twe1/0/6', 't1-a-3 Twe1/0/44']
['t2-a-2 Twe1/0/7', 't1-a-4 Twe1/0/43']
['t2-a-2 Twe1/0/8', 't1-a-4 Twe1/0/44']
['t2-a-3 Twe1/0/1', 't1-a-1 Twe1/0/45']
['t2-a-3 Twe1/0/2', 't1-a-1 Twe1/0/46']
['t2-a-3 Twe1/0/3', 't1-a-2 Twe1/0/45']
['t2-a-3 Twe1/0/4', 't1-a-2 Twe1/0/46']
['t2-a-3 Twe1/0/5', 't1-a-3 Twe1/0/45']
['t2-a-3 Twe1/0/6', 't1-a-3 Twe1/0/46']
['t2-a-3 Twe1/0/7', 't1-a-4 Twe1/0/45']
['t2-a-3 Twe1/0/8', 't1-a-4 Twe1/0/46']
['t2-a-4 Twe1/0/1', 't1-a-1 Twe1/0/47']
['t2-a-4 Twe1/0/2', 't1-a-1 Twe1/0/48']
['t2-a-4 Twe1/0/3', 't1-a-2 Twe1/0/47']
['t2-a-4 Twe1/0/4', 't1-a-2 Twe1/0/48']
['t2-a-4 Twe1/0/5', 't1-a-3 Twe1/0/47']
['t2-a-4 Twe1/0/6', 't1-a-3 Twe1/0/48']
['t2-a-4 Twe1/0/7', 't1-a-4 Twe1/0/47']
['t2-a-4 Twe1/0/8', 't1-a-4 Twe1/0/48']
```